# braintree payment gateway integration with PHP step by step

Tags: php, braintree

I am new to braintree integration with PHP, i have searched in the internet i am not able to get correct one to implement in my website.

Can anyone help to to integration of braintree for my website with step by step including the sandbox creation .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/Braintree.php';
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox'); /* this is sandbox or production */
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('Your ID');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('Your Public Key');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('Your Private key');

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
    'amount' => $amount,
    'orderId' => 'Your Order ID' , /* It should be unique */
    'creditCard' => array(
        'number' =>  '41111111111111111',
        'expirationDate' => '07/16',
        'cardholderName' => 'NAME',
    )
));

if ($result->success) {
    /* your success condition */
}else if ($result->transaction) {
    $msg .= "Error processing transaction:<br>" ;
    $msg .="\n  code: " . $result->transaction->processorResponseCode ;
    $msg .="\n  text: " . $result->transaction->processorResponseText ;
    echo $msg ; 
}
```

Comment: Login to Braintree account you will get the keys on dashboard. Create sandbox account from  https://www.braintreepayments.com/get-started